# Webcontrol not showing Captcha

Tags: c#, vb.net, captcha, recaptcha

For a simple project, I have a webcontrol docked on a panel in my form that can access any webpage via *navigate*

`WebControl1.Navigate("the webpage")`

However, some pages requiring input of a reCaptcha do not show in my webcontrol at all.

How do I show all captcha with my webcontrol? are there references I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the reCaptcha properly - assuming it is Google reCaptcha you need to include a script from Google and then run initialization to load and render it via a call.

Something like this inside script tags:

script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit"

Comment: how do you call this inside your vb.net webcontrol?